# Requests timed out or cancelled

Tags: c#, flurl

I get the exception

> FlurlHttpException`with the message`Call timed out.

The `InnerException` exception is of class `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`.

I am a little confused. Does it mean that the request timed out or request was canceled?

Comment: The `FlurlHttpException` with the message "Call timed out" usually indicates that the request took longer than the specified timeout period, and the exception was triggered because of this timeout.